# Desearilizing Xml with multiple InnerText Nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I am having trouble with deserializing a XML into C# Model. I am pulling that XML from external API, so i have no control over it. It has multiple "InnerText" nodes, that serialized cant deserialize correctly(last one wins, orhers are lost).

I`ve already fixed this using XmlDocument Class, but i need to do it with model instead.

The XML i am trying to deserialize:

```
    <root>
         <passage>
              <hlword>Test</hlword> 
              your Internet.....
              <hlword>test</hlword> 
              from Ookla.
          </passage>
     </root>
```

C# Classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "passage")]
public class Passage
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "hlword")]
    public List<string> Hlword { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string InnerText { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "passage")]
    public List<Passage> Passage { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string InnerText { get; set; }
}
```

From example above, i need to extract: "Test your internet..... test from Ookla", Instead I am getting List of Passage class with 2 Hlwords (inner text "test") and inner text on Root class "from Ookla". All the text after  elements is ommited.

Comment: I believe without a complete XML tag, it will not be converted to a class object using serialization. Those free text inside the parent element will be omitted.

Comment: Very simple.  Make InnerText an array : public string[] InnerText { get; set; }

Comment: @jdweng This actually works. I`ve tried list before, but without success. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the innertext using XmlDocument

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
var text = doc.SelectSingleNode("root/passage").InnerText;
```